# HttpWebRequest underlying connection closed Event/Notification

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, httpwebrequest, timeout

I have a .NET service with a client/server architecture where the client machines get connections to server machines through a software load balancer. I set the `HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout` property to a specific value so that the connection would be terminated every while and the SLB would give the client a new connection to a different (or potentially the same) server in case the server was misbehaving.

My question is:

Is there a way to get notified whenever the `ConnectionLeaseTimeout` interval is exhausted and a new connection to a new server is initiated? I would like to log the information of the new server every time this happens to make sure that I am indeed renewing the connection and not just holding to a certain machine for longer than I should.

I'm hoping there's some built-in support for this scenario and that I don't have to store the information of the current host and keep checking every while (every few requests or every interval of time) that I'm connected to a new server (by comparing to the previous) and keeping track of times of change. Even if I do that, there's no way to tell if in two successive intervals of time I'm connected to the same server because I didn't release the first connection, or because the SLB gave me back the same server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a lease timeout is that you don't know when (in your code) it's going to happen because it would be asynchronous to your code.  So, *if* it did notify you of a disconnection, it would have to be on some worker thread and you'd simply have to store that information and use it when your main thread got to a point where it could do anything with that information.  That point is generally the next time you want to do something with the web request.  So, the only real thing you can do to detect this is to simply catch the resulting `WebException` on the next use of the request.

Comment: I get your point, but for now I just want to log that event which is OK to happen on a concurrent thread... To give you more context, the SLB people are claiming that I'm holding onto the machines too long and I want to prove to them that this is not the case and that the SLB actually keeps giving me the same machine back.

Comment: There isn't an event.  You'd have to try to send something on the connect to see if it is still connected.  If it's http, you likely can't do that.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just wanted to make sure there's no out-of-the-box solution before I implement something...